# Weird Shell page and ListView Navigation issue [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I have a rather peculiar issue. My page has a list view with bunch of view cells containing appointment information. Now when user taps the list view entry they are redirected to appointment detail page using Shell.Current.GoToAsync(). On that page user can go back either through button press or through shell's back arrow.

Case 1.) When they press the Button "OK" - all works as intended, they go back to the page with listview, they can tap on any entry and it will open once.

Case 2.) When using back arrow, the page renders additional method run inside listview.itemtapped method, which I called OnListViewApptFinishedTapped. So every time the user goes back using the arrow, next time they press on any item from the list view, multiple appointment detail pages will open.

I hope I explained it well enough to get the gist of it. I have a temporary workaround with counter inside the ontap method, but it's definitely suboptimal.

Any pointers welcome!

Comment: Which means a normal button works, while the default back on the top not? Post your code would be helpful for suggestions.

Comment: Could you please post a small video to elaborate your problem?

Comment: Hi!

Sorry for such a late response - I was out of town.

Here's a quick video, you see how the shell opens multiple subpages? I have no clue why:

[Link to YT](https://youtu.be/3lKMZXInbbw?list=UUTjLiIqFE2Y9tCfQit0ILqQ) **Link to vid**

Comment: Is it convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?